# blender cache on several computers

Tags: network, cache

I have multiple low-performance computers, and I was wondering: could blender cache the same animation on all of them?
Now notice, I want to cache, not render. I know there are lots of answers out there for rendering, but this is asking about caching.

Comment: are you only interested in caching animation data, or other data like smoke sim, particles, dynamic paint, physics etc?

Comment: caching smoke, particles, etc.